# RoleLeaderSerializer' object is not callable?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I try to get I receive this error object is not callable

**model**

```
class RoleLeader(AbstractUser):
    cellphone = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photoleaderprofile')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**serializer**

```
class RoleLeaderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
        Serialziador para ver usuarios y sus roles
    """

    class Meta:
        model = RoleLeader
        fields = '__all__'
```

**viewset**

```
class RoleLeaderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = RoleLeader.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoleLeaderSerializer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i ran your app but I didn't have any problems

Make sure you set the below code in the settings

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<YourAppName>.<YourClassName>'
```

or

**Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'RoleLeader.groups'**

and

**Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'RoleLeader.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.**